# Closure only works when assigned to new variable - Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

I have started learning about closures and, although I'm starting to get my head around them, there is one part that doesn't make sense.

In the code below, when I invoke the original function, `addSomething()`, the calculation doesn't happen, however, when I assign this function to a new variable `var all = addSomething();` it does then produce the required result i.e. it does the math and returns `6` in the console.

Can someone explain two things:

1) Am I doing this correctly?

2) Why does the calculation only execute when the original function is assigned to a new variable?

I'm finding this part very confusing.

```js
function addSomething() {
  var a = 2,b = 4;
  
  function addIt() {
    var total = a + b;
    return total;
  }
  
  return addIt;
}

var all = addSomething();
console.log(all());
```

Comment: `console.log(addSomething()())` will work too... To answer your questions: 1) yes 2) no it does not?

Comment: Can you explain what _"when I invoke the original function the calculation doesn't happen"_ means? Do you mean when you execute `addSomething` **alone** you don't get the desired result?

Comment: hi @ibrahimmahrir i've edited the question to make it clearer. thanks

Comment: I think the bit that is confusing you is that you've added `()` to the end of `all` which is what is making it 'work'

Comment: I hope I could clarify your doubts with my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because if you are wrapping functions. The first call returns a function, and the second call returns the actual value.

You call `addSomething` that returns `addIt` which is another function. Thats why you need the second `()` in order to get the value returned by `addIt`.

In your approach you are storing the returned value of `addSomething` (the function addIt) in a variable called `all`. `all() == addSomething()()`

```js
function addSomething() {
  var a = 2,b = 4;
  
  function addIt() {
    var total = a + b;
    return total;
  }
  
  return addIt;
}

console.log(addSomething()());
```

Comment: Thanks @CristianS. That was really useful.  Annoying that someone down-voted the question's only upvote though.